# SCRAPY Pagination:Is there a way to crawl websites with scrapy when there are no numbers for the paginations?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am working on a project to scrape the yahoo finance most active stocks (URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active) with scrapy.

Currently, there are 152 stocks under this and 25 are displayed per page. Usually, in most of the scenarios I have found online, if one is scraping a website with pagination, the go-to method is find the number of pages required in the HTML of the first page using Xpath/CSS selectors and loop over them. With my current website, I am facing the following scenario:

1. There are no explicit "number of pages" in the HTML.
2. At the bottom of the page, the next and previous buttons do not have any javascript or link for the next page. I am not an expert on HTML so I may be overlooking something elementary(if so, I apologize in advance). The HTML for the button is given below:

```html
<button class="Va(m) H(20px) Fz(s) Bd(0) M(0) P(0) Bdendc($seperatorColor) O(n):f Bdendw(1px) Bdends(s) Pend(10px) Fw(500) C($linkColor)"><svg class="Va(m)! Fill($linkColor)! Stk($linkColor)! Cur(p)" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="caret-left" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0; vertical-align: bottom;">
<path d="M16.14 24.102L28.865 36.83c.78.78 2.048.78 2.828 0 .78-.78.78-2.047 0-2.828l-9.9-9.9 9.9-9.9c.78-.78.78-2.047 0-2.827-.78-.78-2.047-.78-2.828 0L16.14 24.102z"></path>
</svg><span class="Va(m)">
<span>Prev</span></span>
</button>
```

3. There is text which tells the total number of stocks is "1-25 of 152". Is there a way to get only the '152' out of this HTML using Xpath and CSS so that I can loop over 152%25 times?

```html
<div class="D(ib) Fz(m) Fw(b) Lh(23px) W(75%)--mobp"><span><!-- react-text: 374 -->Matching <!-- /react-text --><span>Stocks</span></span><span class="Mstart(15px) Fw(500) Fz(s)"><span>1-25 of 152 results</span></span>
</div>
```

4. In the URL once we click on the Next button at the bottom of the page, since there are no page numbers in the subsequent URLs,  the URL has a count and offset parameter which is updated on each click of next or prev

> https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset=0
> https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset=25
> https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset=50
> https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset=75

As a last resort, if I'm unable to get the pagination sorted, how can I loop over the URL such that every loop will increment the offset parameter by 25?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=152`

Just use the parameter `count` in the link with the number of stocks you want to display.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I forgot to add this point, if I use the URL with the count and run the spider, it does not crawl 152 but only 25(which is the default setting) whereas if I physically enter the URL with count 152, it loads everything.

Comment: Show me your spider

Comment: Hi Torpedo, Thank you for your comment, I was able to get to the solution thanks to that in part. I will post the solution as a answer to the post where I will share my spider.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to get working:
For the string "1-25 of 152 results" I split it and got 152 and converted it to integer. Then I divided the 152 by 25 and added 1 to get the total number of pages required. After that I generated a list of multiples of 25 till the total number of pages(7 in this case). And I looped over it and made calls. Code below:

```js
    def get_stock_count(self,response):
        count = str(response.xpath('// *[ @ id = "fin-scr-res-table"] / div[1] / div[1] / span[2] / span').css('::text').extract())
        total_results = int(count.split()[-2])
        total_offsets = total_results//25 + 1
        offset_list = [i*25 for i in range(total_offsets)]
        for offset in offset_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset={offset}', callback=self.load_pagination)
```

Added this and scraped the page in the subsequent call(load_pagination)

My full spider code:

```html
  name = 'apartmentspider'
def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active']
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_stock_count)

def get_stock_count(self,response):
    count = str(response.xpath('// *[ @ id = "fin-scr-res-table"] / div[1] / div[1] / span[2] / span').css('::text').extract())
    total_results = int(count.split()[-2])
    total_offsets = total_results//25 + 1
    offset_list = [i*25 for i in range(total_offsets)]
    for offset in offset_list:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset={offset}', callback=self.load_pagination)

def load_pagination(self, response):
    stocks = response.xpath('//*[@id="scr-res-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody//tr/td[1]/a').css('::text').extract()
    for stock in stocks:
        print(stock)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}?p={stock}', callback= self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    items = ApartmentsprojectItem() 
#Only added few fields for brevity
    items['stock_name']      = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1').css('::text').extract()
    items['intraday_price']  = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]').css('::text').extract()
    items['price_change']    = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[2]').css('::text').extract()
    yield items
```